# RDC into Ubuntu Server with Ubuntu Desktop running

Tags: 16.04, remote

I get an X window and then I get a

> login successful for display, started connection.

Then I get a

> connecting to "127.0.0.1 5911". tcp connected then error - problem connecting.

This is from the Connection Log dialog box. It stays up in RDC window.
If I click `OK`, I get a dialog box from `xrdp` with Module dropdown box defaulted to `sesman-Xvnc` and 2 input fields for username and password.
If I complete the entries and click Ok it comes right back to the Connection Log.

Is it a port number issue?
And do I have to export my DISPLAY from a Terminal window or in the .profile?
I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing mate desktop.  Apparently there are known problems with the other desktops through RDP.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by installing mate desktop. Apparently there are known problems with the other desktops through RDP.
Got this from Griffon's IT Library.
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952